# PHP - if error occurs, send email

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

Lately there have a couple of php errors on my clients website. Although they don't stop the website working they can stop certain parts working temporarily.

Is there anyway i can send an email when this occurs. For example earlier today the site got this error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database`.`table`, CONSTRAINT `XXXX` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `xxxxxx` (`xxxx)' in...
```

The only way of currently noticing this or other particular error is if someone brings it to our attention on the site but i want to be able to get an email if this occurs just by simply using

```
mail('my@email.com','subject',$err);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: If you use try/catch blocks where you catch errors you can send an e-mail in the catch.

Comment: Prepare to have your inbox destroyed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try{
    // your query
} catch($e){
    mail('my@email.com','error on query',$e->getMessage());

}
```